# Highcharts Populating Realtime Data with Time

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have been looking all around for a couple of days and testing different samples but I have not been able to figure this out and I hope someone knows an answer to this, thanks a lot. I am creating a chart and populating the data from my db. I am looking for a way to make it redraw the chart every 5 seconds. I have tried using setInterval and setTimeout and charts.redraw() and other solutions I have found reading several different samples, but haven't managed to get it working.

I have the following code:

```
 $(function () {

    var reports= new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "reports",
            defaultSeriesType: "area"
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                color: "#1875d3",
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                lineWidth: 4,
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: "#FFFFFF"
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Reports",
            data: <%= seriesarray %>
        }],
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            labels: {
                x: 15,
                y: 15,
                style: {
                    color: "#999999",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "10px"
                }
            },
            gridLineColor: "#e7e7e7"
        },
        xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: "#e7e7e7",
            labels: {
                x: 15,
                y: -5,
                style: {
                    color: "#268ccd",
                    fontSize: "10px"
                }
            },
            categories: <%= categoriesarray %>
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return "Visits: " + this.y;
            },
            borderColor: "#333333"
        },
        credits: false,
        title: false,
        exporting: false,
        legend: false
    });
});
```

In the codebehind I have a method that gets the data from my db and converts the result into JSON:

e.g.

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 seriesarray = jss.Serialize(value1); 
 categoriesarray = jss.Serialize(value2);
```

I also created a different version calling a web service as follow:

```
        $().ready(function () {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        //var series = this.series[0];
                        //var seriesData = getData();
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                            chart.series[0].setData(getData(), true);
                            //setTimeout(getData, 500);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                gridLineColor: "#e7e7e7",
                labels: {
                    x: 15,
                    y: -5,
                    style: {
                        color: "#268ccd",
                        fontSize: "10px"
                    }
                },
              },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: null
              },
              labels: {
                  x: 15,
                  y: 15,
                  style: {
                      color: "#999999",
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      fontSize: "10px"
                  }
              },
              gridLineColor: "#e7e7e7"
          },
          tooltip: {
              headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
              pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                  '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
              footerFormat: '</table>',
              shared: true,
              useHTML: true
          },
          plotOptions: {
              series: {
                  color: "#1875d3",
                  fillOpacity: 0.1,
                  lineWidth: 4,
                  marker: {
                      radius: 5,
                      lineWidth: 1,
                      lineColor: "#FFFFFF"
                  }
              }
          },
          series: getData()
      });

      function getData() {
          var retvalue;
          $.ajax({
              url: 'Test.aspx/getData',
              data: [],
              dataType: 'json',
              type: 'POST',
              async: false,
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              success: function (data) {
                  retvalue = eval(data.d);
                  //setTimeout(getData, 2000);
              },
              cache: false,
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  var errorData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  $.each(errorData, function (key, value) {
                      if (key == 'Message') {
                          alert(value);
                          retvalue = "0";
                      }
                  });
              }
          })
          return retvalue;
      }
  });
```

The chart draws just fine in both examples but it doesn't update in real time which is what I need. On my second example, I actually not getting the categories showing in the xAxis because I couldn't find the syntax to add that to the second version.

Anyone knows how can I get the chart to draw again so it gets the real time data from my db?

**LATEST UPDATE**

This is now the closest I am from getting this done after spending the weekend figuring the syntax out:

```
 var chart;
    var c = [];
    var d = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: getData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: c
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: d
            }]
        });
    });

    /**
    * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
    */
    function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Test.aspx',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var categories = [];
                var seriesData = [];
                $.each(data, function () {
                    categories.push(this.data);
                    seriesData.push(parseInt(this.count));
                });
                chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
                chart.series[0].setData(seriesData);
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

Test.aspx gets this from my DB:

19 Aug  1
20 Aug  0
21 Aug  2
22 Aug  3
23 Aug  1
24 Aug  0
25 Aug  0

then I convert this to JSON:

{"19 Aug":1,"20 Aug":0,"21 Aug":2,"22 Aug":3,"23 Aug":1,"24 Aug":0,"25 Aug":0,"26 Aug":0}

e.g. 19 Aug = horizontal data
     1 = Vertical data

See below for what I get, no errors at all. Anyone knows how can I get the data to show now? thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Have you have looked at their demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/) about that same functionality?

Comment: yes I have ssarabando, that sample uses random data and did not help to figure out the syntax to change that to use real data. what I need is to find a way for my chart to refresh every 5 seconds with new data from the database. it is actually not real-time for that matter as there is a 5 second delay.

Comment: Please see if this jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/fMEj8/) puts you on the right track. I've just modified their example a bit to add AJAX calls to the mix. Also, I believe you want to replace the series each time; if I'm wrong let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot ssarabando, i want to replace the series yes with new data from the database as it gets. sometimes will be the same series sometimes updated depending on traffic as I am pulling out traffic statistics from the db.

Comment: no yet :(, I am trying to figure out the syntax because on your example you are modifying the xAxis with current time but I dont need to do that as I need x and y coming from my db. I have modified the function to call my web service but right now i get nothing, need to find out the syntax

Comment: Sorry, that's because the example I used as base was the Highchart's one. For a category chart, just return an array of points and use the series' `setData` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ssarabando/fMEj8/2/).

Comment: Hi Carol.Can you please show me the cs code for this. I am new to json jquery. I need help. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your for to this one:

```
            $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                categories.push(i);
                seriesData.push(parseInt(e));
            });
```

Comment: thanks but I already looked at this example and didn't help much. this example is for real-time monitoring of data and it shows in the xAxis the time. I am not looking to do this. I am only trying to get my data updated on a chart as information gets changed on my database. I have seen this example already but did not help. thanks anyway.

Comment: fantastic, thank you so much Pawel Fus, that was exactly what I needed, thanks again.