# Ajax call to get data to highchart

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, highcharts

I am trying to make a spline chart using highcharts that updates every second.
The data comes from the DB.

**my script is :**

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        var c = [];
        var d = [];
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: getData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'PUNCHING DETAILS'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: c
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'punching'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value ;
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                crosshairs: true,
                shared: true
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'PUNCHING',                    
                data: d
            }]
        });
    });


    function getData() {
        alert("hi");
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                var categories = [];
                var seriesData = [];
                $.each(data, function (i, e) {
                    categories.push(i);
                    seriesData.push(parseInt(e));
                });
                chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
                chart.series[0].setData(seriesData);
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            { 
                alert(errorThrown); 
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
</script>
```

And cs code is :

```
public partial class ajax_main_Testpages_Realtime_Graph_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
 public static string GetData()
 {
    String con1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString();
    List<string> list_time = new List<string>();
    List<int> list_count = new List<int>();
    var serie_line_Dept = new { data = new List<object>() };
    string query = @"select item_count,entered_time p_time from st_request where rownum<=10";
    OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(con1);
    connection.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmdSelect = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmdSelect.CommandText = query;
    OdbcDataReader readerSelect = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
    while (readerSelect.Read())
    {
        serie_line_Dept.data.Add(new List<object>() { readerSelect["p_time"].ToString(), int.Parse(readerSelect["item_count"].ToString()) });

        list_time.Add(readerSelect["p_time"].ToString());
        list_count.Add(int.Parse(readerSelect["item_count"].ToString()));
    }
    JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return oSerializer1.Serialize(serie_line_Dept);
}
}
```

**I get the this error**: Unexpected token <.

No graph is displayed.
I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397809/highcharts-populating-realtime-data-with-time) for the above code.
I am new to json and jquery, I am unable to solve this.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do HTML encode before serializing.

Comment: U mean i need to do this? return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(oSerializer1.Serialize(serie_line_Dept));

Comment: Can you please help me doing this

Comment: First of all, have you tried to debug this? At what point your are getting error?

Comment: I find no errors in the console. If i comment the line datatype:JSON then there is no error  and no graph.

Comment: So, where you get Unexpected token < ? For received data in Jquery? Can you put debug point at line return oSerializer1.Serialize(serie_line_Dept);
and check result and let know ? What is getting pushed in categories?

Comment: I get the error in javascript alert.

Comment: Ok. Can you put debug point at line return oSerializer1.Serialize(serie_line_Dept); and check result and let know ? What is getting pushed in categories?

Comment: Check if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573127/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-on-chrome

Comment: Nothing worked for me

Comment: How your json looks like ?

Comment: {"data":[["3042",4],["4044",5],["3042",2],["4044",50],["4044",4],["4044",2],["40‌​44",1],["4044",4],["4044",4],["4044",4]]}

Comment: I am badly stuck with this. Anyone can help me out please

Comment: Need to debug step by step. Can you comment code after line success: function (data) {
console.log(data)
and check.

Comment: The error comes before that. So no data comes in console.Using debugger, the errors shows on these two lines :    div.querySelectorAll("*,:x");  and matches.call(div, "[s!='']:x");  I suspect the data  from my code behind is wrong. I am unable to find that

Comment: Is the json that i am sending is correct?

Comment: Your JSON is valid. check on http://jsonlint.com/. Can you check ajax request response using fiddler too

Comment: I still did not solve this. JSON should be in this format. {"19 Aug":1,"20 Aug":0,"21 Aug":2,"22 Aug":3,"23 Aug":1,"24 Aug":0,"25 Aug":0,"26 Aug":0}. I do not know how to get it